# How to select image from image xcassets based on user device

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am currently working on an app which runs on both iPad and iPhones. 
My login screen has an image attached to it on a UIImageView.

The problem is that the image stretches if the app is opened on an iPad.

I was wondering whether I can images of different sizes i.e ( iPhone 5,5s, 6, 6 plus, iPad Air etc ) into my image assets folder and based on the type of user device the UIImageView will automatically choose the correct image.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just select Device Specific in you attribute inspector, for an image, to view all of them.

[image]

Edit: and of course, select the devices which you would like to use :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does the device automatically selects the image based on the device being used? or Do I need to program the UIImageView to pick the correct image based on the device being used?

Comment: No, iOS is smart that way, and know which image to load :)